# pip install mod_wsgi failed. Window server 12, python 3.6.4 64 bit vc++14

Tags: django, apache, pip, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy my django app to a win server12 64bit. The latest apache is installed on the server( from apacheloung distro). build tool is vc15 build tool. Python 3.6.4 64bit. I follow the instruction of https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst
But I kept getting the error message like
....

> src/server\mod_wsgi.c(4417): error C2065: 'wsgi_daemon_process':
>   undeclared identifier
>       src/server\mod_wsgi.c(4417): error C2223: left of '->group' must point to struct/union
>       src/server\mod_wsgi.c(6052): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from '__int64' to 'long', possible loss of data
>       error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command ""d:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools,
> ```
>
> tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\ccsadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3ktbwpy9\mod-wsgi\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --recor
>   d
>   C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-aw2siwjx-record\install-record.txt
>   -- single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3ktbwpy9\mod-wsgi\

I have researched online and couldn't find anything similar to my situation. I have compiled successfully on my dev machine(win 10, python 3.64 32 bit)

Please advise.

Comment: can you format your code please. [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Try ``pip install 'mod_wsgi<4.6.0'``. Looks like change in 4.6.0 has broken ability to build on Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much! The one that works in my dev is 4.5.24. When I run the pip install 'mod_wsgi<4.6.0', error mess "the system cannot find the file specified". How can I download the older version in windows?

Comment: pip install mod_wsgi==4.5.24 works. Thank you so much for pointing out the version issue!

Comment: No one had told me the latest versions were failing to install on Windows, so I will work out fix and get a new version released. Thanks.

Comment: If it is at all possible, if you try installing ``develop`` branch of GitHub repo for mod_wsgi by using ``pip install -U https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/develop.zip`` that will tell me if fix worked or whether is further changes I need to make. I don't have easy way of building on Windows at the moment.

Comment: I just tried. it failed. win10 python 3.6 32bit, apachev15 32 bit. vc15 32bit. >> ...unning setup.py install for mod-wsgi ... error
    Complete output from command c:\...\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-m5yenhbv-build\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-cgejiwzj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Comment: can't post long message. Hope this will help.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't include the details I need to see as to why fails. If you can drop full details in issue at https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi that would be appreciated. BTW, when using Python 3.6 you should be using VC14 of MS compiler, not VC15. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: version 4.5.24 also failed with error code 1.... how?